# JavaScript: Get Element by ID and Scroll to Top

Tags: javascript

I've got a contact form at the top of the page, the first input field has the id of "input_1_1". In the content text there is a "Contact Us" link which should jump to the top of the page and select the first input field, the code looks like this.

```
<a href="javascript:document.getElementById('input_1_1').focus()">Contact us</a>
```

This work perfectly in Chrome and scrolls right to the top and selects the first field, in Firefox however the page doesn't scroll right to the top and because of this you can only see the first input field and not the form heading.

How can the this code be modified to scroll to the top of the page and select the first input field rather than just selecting the first input field.

Thanks in advance
Willem Louw

Comment: Can you share your complete HTML code?

Comment: Basically the form input looks like this:

`<input name="input_1" id="input_1_1" type="text" value="" class="medium" tabindex="1">`

and then the link look like this:

`<a href="javascript:document.getElementById('input_1_1').focus()">Contact us</a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<a href="javascript:scrollWin()">Contact us</a>

<script>
function scrollWin()
{
   window.scrollTo(0,0);// set the proper x and y coordinates for your contact form. 
   document.getElementById('input_1_1').focus()
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do a label around the link like this

```
<label for="input_1_1"><a href="#input_1_1">Contact us</a></label>
```